# How to find the correct workout plan for myself

Tags: workout-routines, workout, workout-types, circuit-training, beginners

I am 26 years old. Ht. 5'6", Wt. 60-67kg. The first time i did weight training, it lasted two months, the second time I tried it, it lasted 3-4 weeks. I have noted the following things which i believe worked against me being regular at gym.

1. I was not sure about the kind of body i was working for. I did not had a proper plan and  was impatient. I don't want to be bulky, i want to remain flexible and still increase my strength. Should Circuit training be a better option than weight training. How is it different?
2. When i work out, i feel tired but i don't feel any tension in my muscles. Is it because i am not doing the exercises right.
3. Sometimes I get headaches in the middle of workouts. Is this because of insufficient diet.

Please suggest some references / links which i can study to prepare a workout plan for me, which could give me insight into the muscle groups. Basically something to guide a beginner like me. I don't find bodybuilding.com particularly helpful for a beginner. Am i wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: If you sweat a lot and you have headaches during your workout, you **could** be dehydrated.  Please consider drinking more water while working out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with simple excercises and learn how to execute those well and learn to feel muscles. I don't think you need to know muscle groups because there are basic excerscises for arms/core/legs which are easy, don't overthink it. It goes along with feeling the muscles, you can read all the internet but unless you spend a lot of time doing actuall work you know nothing. I think 3-4 weeks should be enough to see how excercises are affecting you and pick those that you don't like because those are probably where you have weak points. If you feel weak, eat more and sleep more or excersice less, skip day or two or make two week vacations from gym.

Not really scientific answer but "how to find workout for yourself" is about going to gym and trying what works and what not. By searching for plan on internet you will not get stronger by trying out different things on gym you will, which will prepare you for further better workouts.